# audio is not working in kali linux and am not able to open pulseaudio

Tags: kali-linux, pulse-audio

Audio is not working.

I downloaded Kali Linux using the WSL 2 GUI and am using it using remote desktop connection.

The audio is not working and I'm not able to open pulse audio mixer.

I have tried all methods online but none are working.

I have tried purging and reinstalling it but still no audio and the audiomixer does not open.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what you have tried.This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: Please use another distro, Kali is targeted at advanced users only.

Comment: I am using Kali here. I do not find it to be well suited to WSL.  Use a different version of Linux.